# Hibernate en un proyecto web con Maven

Tags: java, java-ee

donde se guarda el archivo hibernate.cfg.xml en un proyecto web con Maven, yo lo coloco en la raiz "src" pero no me funciona.
Gracias

Comment: Se suele colocar en *src/resources*

Comment: src/main/resources